# Making thumbnails responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having issues making a client's website responsive. I'd like for all the thumbnails below the pages' main image to line up with the main image's right and left sides, but I'm not sure if that's possible when trying to make them responsive with percentage widths. Is there a work-around that is cross-browser compatible? I've searched and searched, tried all sorts of ghetto-rigged stuff, but so far no luck. Here's her site: http://www.courtneykingstudios.com/

This is how I WANT it to look in all screen sizes:
[image: This is how I WANT it to look in all screen sizes]

This is how it's currently getting distorted in smaller screen sizes:
[image: This is how it's currently getting distorted in smaller screen sizes]

Comment: Post your code in the question. The link you provided will be irrelevant to future visitors once you fix the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `margins` in `px`, I think that is the problem. And I do not know why you have `padding-left` set on the `#wrapper` for thumbnails when your "how I WANT" does not suggest you want that. Also you should post your codes!

Solution (for, when you do not want gap in the end and beginning of 5 thumbnails arranged in a row):

```
.thumb1 {
    width: 19%;
    margin: 0.5% 0 0.5% 1.25%;
    float: left;
}

.thumb1:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Note that you do not need to change the `%`s in CSS @media (for different screen sizes) unless you want to change the number of thumbnails in a row.

Plus remove the `padding`s from `#wrapper` if you do not need.